# How can i break line html text in Elm

Tags: elm

I have a text like this

`Special menu:\nFrenchfire 1ea\nHamborger 2ea\nMeatball 1ea`

and i want to breakline it in Elm with Html tag such as `pre` or `span`
and it should show like this

```
Special menu:
Frenchfire 1ea
Hamborger 2ea
Meatball 1ea
```

i have no idea to concat `br[][]` in string if it is an Elm
but if javascript i can replace string like `replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')` and it done.

Comment: what is current output?

Comment: i write a code like
``` 
div []
                        (List.map
                            (\s ->
                                span []
                                    [ text s
                                    , br [] []
                                    ]
                            )
                            (String.replace "\n" text)
                        )
```

but i have error This `replace` call produces:

    #String -> String#

But `map` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    #List String#

Comment: `String.replace` takes input of type String and returns a String. `List.map` requires an input as List of Strings i.e. List String as the error states. Instead of replace, maybe you could use `String.split`? That'll remove the newline chars and return a List of Strings. EDIT: `String.lines` already breaks the String on newline char and returns a List of String, better to use that.

Comment: @kaskelotti You should make that a proper answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You mentioned a `<pre>` tag, so let's try that first:

```
import Html exposing (pre, text)

pre []
    [ text "Special menu:\nFrenchfire 1ea\nHamborger 2ea\nMeatball 1ea" ]
```

Renders as:

```
Special menu:
Frenchfire 1ea
Hamborger 2ea
Meatball 1ea
```

Or you could split the string into individual lines. `String.split` accomplishes this:

```
String.split "\n" "Special menu:\nFrenchfire 1ea\nHamborger 2ea\nMeatball 1ea"
```

Even better, as [kaskelotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337120/kaskelotti) aptly suggested:

```
String.lines "Special menu:\nFrenchfire 1ea\nHamborger 2ea\nMeatball 1ea"
```

Use `List.map` to transform the Strings into Html and `List.intersperse` to insert `<br />` tags between them:

```
import Html exposing (br, text)
List.intersperse (br [] [])
        (List.map text
            (String.lines "Special menu:\nFrenchfire 1ea\nHamborger 2ea\nMeatball 1ea")
        )
```

You end up with a list of Html elements. Done!

See it rendered [here](https://ellie-app.com/6r8jXLPBg57a1).

Or, if you prefer, use an itemized list:

```
import Html exposing (Html, div, h3, li, text, ul)


listItem : String -> Html msg
listItem content =
    li [] [ text content ]


main : Html msg
main =
    let
        split =
            String.lines "Special menu:\nFrenchfire 1ea\nHamborger 2ea\nMeatball 1ea"

        headline =
            Maybe.withDefault "Items:" (List.head split)

        items =
            Maybe.withDefault [] (List.tail split)
    in
    div []
        [ h3 [] [ text headline ]
        , ul [] (List.map listItem items)
        ]
```

See it rendered [here](https://ellie-app.com/6r85SJ3s4rfa1).

Answer (score 2):

`String.replace` takes input of type String and returns a String. `List.map` requires an input as List of Strings i.e. List String as the error states.

You can solve this by using `String.split` or `String.lines`. Both will take a String as input and return a List of String, which is what `List.map` requires.

The difference is that `String.lines` is a built-in function meant for splitting the String with newline chars (\n) and `String.split` is a general purpose utility for splitting a String by any delimiter.

For this particular case, I'd go with `String.lines`, since the name documents its purpose already. Presence of `String.split` is good to know for future cases.