# How do I add a Html line break in Elm-Ui?

Tags: html, line, break, elm, elm-ui

I an using Elm-UI and I would like add an Html `<br>` tag, but I am not sure how. `\n` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parsing a line breaks like `\n` from your input is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568074/how-can-i-break-line-html-text-in-elm).

Though because `br [] []` is not part of Elm-Ui, and Elm-Ui does not have a similar attribute, the solution is to pipe the line break through `Element.html`.

For example:

```
import Element exposing (html, paragraph, text)
import Html exposing (br)

-- Snip

paragraph []
    [ text "first line"
    , html <| br [] []
    , text "second line"
    ]
```